# Does IronPython .net based DLL need to be deployed with Python Standard Library if it uses the Standard Library?

Tags: .net, python, ironpython

If I reference the Python Standard Library using IronPython do I have to deploy any Python related libraries or runtimes along with my .net dll?  Or, can I just deploy the dll?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to deploy the python libraries you're referencing along with your dll. it wont be included statically in there for you.